# How do I end up with a negative value in this chain of transformations?

Tags: c++

I am displaying pressure values in the range of 0 - 5, with two decimal places. However recently I got a negative value -0.05 shown.

Can someone explain how this tranformation chain can end up with a negative value? The only idea I have right now is an unreasonably high input value, but maybe I am not seeing something.

(Copied together from various source files)

```
double value = <the input value in bar>;
value -= 1; //subtract atmospheric pressure
value *= 100; // preserve decimal places

unsigned int ui_value = static_cast<unsigned int>(value);
int intValue = ui_value;  // uint value is input into a function taking int as argument
double v = ((double)intValue) / std::pow(10.0f, 2);  // scale back

std::stringstream tmp;
tmp << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << v;
```

Somehow this ended up giving me -0.05. I have no idea what the input was, but if everything was functioning correctly, then it should have been a bar value around 2.5 - 3.5.

What happened here that could have resulted in a negative value?? Note that there were 4 pressure sensors all giving the same wonky result, so I somewhat doubt it was a hardware issue, but at the same time I don't see how a "normal" input value could have resulted in a negative value here. Even with a negative input I would expect the conversion to uint to get rid of the sign and give a wrong but positive result.

In case this is somehow compiler dependent, I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: `unsigned int ui_value = static_cast<unsigned int>(value);
int intValue = ui_value;`?  What is the point of casting to unsigned int then to int?

Comment: Why `std::pow(10.0f, 2);` instead of `100.0f`?

Comment: @KamilCuk The comment says it: It's passed into a function that takes an int. Those two things happen in two different dlls. That's how far apart they are.

Comment: `double value = 0.95` would result in `-0.05`. So there is some real code that has a function that takes an int that you are not showing here. Instead you posted some different code. Well, show the real code, please create an [MCVE].

Comment: If you start with `value = 0` you get `unsigned int ui_value = static_cast<unsigned int>(-100);`  and then `int intValue = ui_value;`. At least one of these two lines causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @KamilCuk So what does static_cast<unsigned int> do to the negative value? I would have expected it strips the sign.

Comment: `I would have expected it strips the sign.` Sure, but then `int intValue = ui_value;` what value do you expect do get after that? `I would have expected it strips the sign` Well, but it doesn't. Technically, the code has undefined behavior at that step.

Comment: @KamilCuk it doesn't strip the sign, it does a roundtrip. `unsigned(-100) == 4294967286`.

Comment: If I input `0.95`, I would expect `value` to change to `-5`, then `ui_value` to `5` and `intValue` also `5`. But definitely not `-5`.

Comment: `then ui_value to 5` Well, so your expectancy is wrong. Conversion between a floating point `double` type to `unsigned` type is undefined if the destination type can't represent the value. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions)

Comment: if you want to strip the sign use `std::abs(x)`

Comment: I'm not sure if `unsigned int ui_value = -100.0;` is well defined as `unsigned int ui_value = UINT_MAX-100;` but `int intValue = ui_value;` is for sure not well defined for a value >`INT_MAX`.

Comment: You should really get the value of value as a first step, before even posting here.

Comment: @kutschkem If you did none of those C-style casts, set the warning / error levels of the compiler to the highest, what warnings / errors do you get?  This could be an issue with ignoring the warnings the compiler is giving you and/or stifling the errors by using C-style casts.

Comment: Sooo. I did a thing: http://cpp.sh/753ma At least with gcc it seems like imputting 0.95 does indeed result in -0.05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion from `double` type to `unsigned` is undefined, when `unsigned` can't "represent" the value of `double`, for example the `double` value is negative. From [cppreference implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions) emphasis mine:

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded. **If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined** (even when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply).

To remove the sign, just use `std::abs` ("abs" is short for [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)). Do:

```
double v = std::abs(value) / 100.0f;
```

Comment: @Thomas Sablik  `but unsigned int can't represent -100.0. Doesn't this comment contradict this answer?` Och my, you are right, I am wrong. I saw `ui_value = -100` (ie. `int` to `unsigned` conversion), but you wrote `ui_value = 100.0`, sorry, my eyes.